# how i can use paginate() after get() ?

Tags: php, laravel-5

i'm need to use paginate but i used get() before for some reasons so 
how i can use `paginate()` after `get() ?` 
when i try

```
$s   = Lists::where('id','>',500)->get();
             $s = $s->paginate(2);
            var_dump($s);
```

i get

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate();
```

i do every thing go skip get() before but it's big problem any one have any idea

sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get() returns a Collection instance and paginate() returns a Paginator instance from the Model, so you can't run paginate() in a chain after get().  There should be little reason to, you're either trying to get the whole collection or you're trying to paginate.  There should be little reason to do both.

```
$s   = Lists::where('id','>',500)->paginate(2)
```